# Global Device Orientation

Tags: ios

I want to keep separate Class "Example: Device Manager" with one property "currentDeviceOrientation". from this how to achieve the following state.

1. When ever app launch first time i want to update the "currentDeviceOrientation" property.
2. When ever app coming from background to foreground i want to update the 
   "current DeviceOrientation" property.
3. According the value of "currentDeviceOrientation" my rootViewController view should get load from - (void)loadView method.

Kindly give good way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`You can use the already built-in methods in` **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

Comment: yes i can use this method. but still i want to store current orientation in my separate class. if i initialize the class object and store the current device orientation. its giving always 0.

Comment: Did you set the property of that variable?

Comment: user1673099 i was not able to post the code kindly share ur mail or something so that i can send to u.